# java- how to check if value exists in JSP page?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, entitymanager

I have a function that check if there is a particular record exists in a table in MYSQL.

Below is this code:

```
public String get_value(long nodeid,String ts) {
    try {
        String sql="Select URL FROM urllink WHERE URL='f0="+nodeid+"&ts="+ts + "'";

        em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();
        if (em == null) {
            throw new Exception("could not found URL object.");
        }
      //  return 1;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();



    }
   return null;
}
```

In my JSP page, I will call this function and pass the parameters to it.

```
String v=fileFacade1.get_value(fileID,date);

  if(v !=null ){ 

// if the records exist in the table, do this

}
```

I am trying to call the function so if there is a record in the table,then enter the if statement and do something but from what I debug, the value of v is always null but there is record from the `singleresult`.

Did I do something wrong?

EDIT:

This is how it looks like now:

```
public String get_value(long nodeid,String ts) {
    try {
        String sql="Select URL FROM urllink WHERE URL='f0="+nodeid+"&ts="+ts + "'";
        if (em == null) {
            throw new Exception("could not found URL object.");
        }
        em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();

        return (String)em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();

      //  return 1;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();



    }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: `em == null` does not mean "no object found" but "your containes is not properly set up". I'd also avoid using raw Sql if at all possible when working with JPA

Comment: I think there is no use of `throw new Exception("could not found URL object.");`  . you can remove it `if (em == null) {
            throw new Exception("could not found URL object.");
        }`

Comment: @AkashShah You are right, it's kinda pointless there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return [getSingleResult()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult())

```
return (String)em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();
```

> Execute a SELECT query that returns a single result.

Comment: So I need to return the result retrieved? Then in my `throw new Exception`, it becomes unreachable?

Comment: @Daredevil you need to move checks before using `em`

Comment: @Daredevil remove duplicate row `em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();`

Comment: @Daredevil you can't, can only also accept answer (V sign to the left)

Comment: Thanks anyway, you saved me a headache

Answer (score 1):

Just wrapp your code inside if else condition, i mean throw an exception when `em` is null or return a single string like following code snippet:

```
public String get_value(long nodeid,String ts) {
    try {
        String sql="Select URL FROM urllink WHERE URL='f0="+nodeid+"&ts="+ts + "'";
        if (em == null) {
            throw new Exception("could not found URL object.");
        }
        else{
           return (String)em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as what I shown in my edit code

Comment: @Daredevil your edited code is also good but made a little mistake just remove `em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();`

Answer (score 0):

Your method always returns null.

Moreover, maybe this is just a snippet and there are things missing from your actual code, but when does `em` get instanciated ? (I'm assuming it's a class variable)

Finally, you're calling `getSingleResult` but not doing anything with the actual result, which is what you should return, as shown in @user7294900 's answer

```
return (String) em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();
```